# iOS screen recording while using external HDMI/VGA output?

Tags: ipad, hdmi, airplay, apple-pencil, screen-recording

On iOS devices, the screen recording feature does not function when an external HDMI or VGA adapter is connected.

My (limited) understanding is that, essentially, iOS uses an AirPlay-like mechanism to encode H.264 video and either send it to the adapter or save to file, although I am not sure why it is not possible to save the encoded stream simultaneously.

However, this is *extremely* annoying, since a very natural use of the iPad (particularly with Pencil) is to present lectures and presentations and record audio+screen at the same time.

Are there any natural workarounds to be able to screen record and output to HDMI at the same time?